# How to configure Windows notifications & actions to receive Teams notifications?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, microsoft-teams

I can set the [Teams notification to "Windows" in the Teams settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-notifications-style-in-teams-0da93820-93d0-4da3-86b6-fc28d19908e3):

[image: Teams notification settings]

but I cannot find Teams as a sender in the [Windows notification & actions config page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-notification-settings-in-windows-8942c744-6198-fe56-4639-34320cf9444e) (showing list sorted by name, from `M` onwards):

[image]

How can I let Teams send notifications through the Windows notifications center?

My Windows version is 1909, build 18363.1916.
My Teams version is 1.4.00.31569 (64-bit). It was last updated on 3-12-2021.